# Get the value of Rich Text Editor in Umbraco backoffice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I've defined a property that is called `Reply`and the document type is `RichTextEditor`.

I cannot get the value of `Reply`. This problem is only for properties that type of it is `RichTextEditor`!!!

How can I get the value of Rich Text Editor in Umbraco backoffice?

I've used `Umbraco 7.x` and `ASP.NET MVC`.

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("Reply.controller", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.SendReply = function () {
        var contentId = $routeParams.id;
        var replyText = $("#Reply").val(); // without value ??? (type of Reply is RichTextEditor)
        var email = $("#Email").val();     // It's OK.
        var dataObj = {
            ReplyText: replyText,
            ContentId: contentId,
            Email: email,
        };
        $http.post("backoffice/Reply/ReplyToIncomingCall/ReplyMessage", dataObj).then
        (
            function (response) {
                alert("YES!");
                //TODO: 
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the value of `Reply`, you can use this code.

```
var replyList = $("[id*='Reply']");

        for (i = 0; i < replyList.length; ++i) {
            var rText = replyList[i].value;
            if (!(rText === "" || rText === null)) {
                replyText = rText;
            }
        }
```